# 403 on `PUT` request on signed url for S3 image upload using lamda

Tags: javascript, rest, amazon-s3, file-upload, aws-lambda

I was trying to create an image uploader to my S3 bucket using a Lambda. But when I try to do a PUT request on the generated signed URL from the lambda I am getting a 403.

I have configured my lambda to be able to s3:putObject and s3:putObjectACL
I have also tried to make my s3 bucket public to allow read and write to it for `Everyone` and have also enabled CORS on my s3 bucket along with my API lambda trigger endpoint.

I am still getting a 403 forbidden when I try to upload an image from my client-side HTML page.

The function is like this:

```
 const uploadS3 = async (uri) =>{
                    const file = new Image();
                    file.src = uri;

                    const url = "API-Endpoint to trigger LAMBDA";
                    fetch(url,
                    {
                     //fetches the signed url
                        method: 'GET',
                        mode:'cors',
                    })
                    .then((res) => res.json())
                    .then((response)=> {
                      console.log(response);
                      console.log(response.uploadURL);

                    // request to try to PUT image to s3 bucket using the signed url
                      fetch(response.uploadURL,{
                        method: 'PUT',
                        headers: {
                          "Content-Type": "image/png"
                        },
                        mode:'cors',
                        body: file
                      })
                      .then((res)=> console.log(res))
                      .catch((res)=> console.log(res))
                    })
                    .catch((err)=>console.log(err))
                  }
```

Where am I going wrong?
Really thankful for your help !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the following headers both when getting the presigned URL on server side and when making the request on the client side with the presigned URL

```
{ headers: { 'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg', 'x-amz-acl': 'public-read' } };
```